# Can't import androidx.datastore.dataStore (trying to recreate Google Codelab Example)

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-datastore

## Problem:

I'm trying to recreate this codelab tutorial project https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-proto-datastore, but Android Studio can't import **androidx.datastore.dataStore**

## Steps:

1. create new Kotlin project with an empty Acivity
2. modify gradle file
3. Switch to Android Studio's Project view
4. create a folder named **proto** inside of app/src/main
5. create and modify file **user_prefs.proto** inside of app/src/main/**proto**
6. Build -> Clean Project -> rebuild project
7. Create a serializer class called **UserPreferencesSerializer**
8. Trying to add the following Code to the empty MainActivity.kt

   > private const val DATA_STORE_FILE_NAME = "user_prefs.pb"
   >
   > private val Context.userPreferencesStore: DataStore
   > by dataStore(
   > fileName = DATA_STORE_FILE_NAME,
   > serializer = UserPreferencesSerializer )

After this step Android Studio marks **dataStore** and shows the warning "**Unresolved reference: dataStore**" I'm also unable to import androidx.datastore.dataStore, but I can't find a missing import in my gradle file. Please, can someone tell me how I can resolve this problem?

## Code:

### build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.12"
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    
    implementation  "androidx.datastore:datastore-core:1.0.0-alpha08"
    implementation  "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0"

}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.10.0"
    }

    // Generates the java Protobuf-lite code for the Protobufs in this project. See
    // https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#customizing-protobuf-compilation
    // for more information.
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### user_prefs.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "com.example.test";
option java_multiple_files = true;

message UserPreferences {
  // filter for showing / hiding completed tasks
  bool show_completed = 1;
}
```

### UserPreferencesSerializer

```
package com.example.test

import androidx.datastore.core.CorruptionException
import androidx.datastore.core.Serializer
import com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.OutputStream

object UserPreferencesSerializer : Serializer<UserPreferences> {
    override val defaultValue: UserPreferences = UserPreferences.getDefaultInstance()
    override suspend fun readFrom(input: InputStream): UserPreferences {
        try {
            return UserPreferences.parseFrom(input)
        } catch (exception: InvalidProtocolBufferException) {
            throw CorruptionException("Cannot read proto.", exception)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun writeTo(t: UserPreferences, output: OutputStream) = t.writeTo(output)
}
```

### MainActivity.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore


private const val DATA_STORE_FILE_NAME = "user_prefs.pb"
private val Context.userPreferencesStore: DataStore<UserPreferences> by dataStore(
    fileName = DATA_STORE_FILE_NAME,
    serializer = UserPreferencesSerializer
)


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `import androidx.datastore.*`

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution: It finally worked after I lowered the gradle version from gradle:7.0.0-alpha09 to gradle:4.1.3 (still know clue why the never version doesn't work)

Comment: Hey I am having this issue also, even though I declare:

    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0"

Whenever I look to the call to datastore the import is:

    import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore
    import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.Preferences

I really don't want to be downgrading the gradle build in order to get this to work.

Any ideas why this is happening? - I have tried removing the core package but then *Unresolved reference: DataStore*

Comment: @dvn This was the only solution that worked for me at that time, and since then I haven't used proton datastore ever again. I will try to figure out a solution during my free time, but to be honest I don't think that anything has changed since I wrote this question.

Comment: @Dev2021 Thanks for the info, I just switched back to using SharedPrefs for now, as I could get it to work either. I was afraid to downgrade gradle in case something else stopped working.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem while working on a project.

I found that I was using `datastore-core` and needed `datastore-preferences`. So I changed my dependency declaration from:

```
implementation 'androidx.datastore:datastore-core:1.0.0-alpha08'
```

to:

```
implementation 'androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0'
```

Possibly there was a breaking change between `alpha08` and the `1.0.0` release.

Answer (score 0):

The `dataStore` delegate is part of the `androidx.datastore:datastore` library.

Add the dependency to your modudle's `build.gradle` file. Replace `$dataStoreVersion` with the version of data store which you use, e.g. `1.0.0`:

```
implementation  "androidx.datastore:datastore:$dataStoreVersion"
```

You can find the available versions [here in Google's Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.datastore/datastore).

After adding this dependency, you can use `by dataStore` by adding the following import to your class:

```
import androidx.datastore.dataStore
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-)
I will try to apply your solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In Android documentation:

```kotlin
val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")
```

This line should be at the top of your code.
See [DataStore documenation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, The problem is simple. **Make sure Gradle is not in offline mode.**

Also, ensure that you use this dependency.

```
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:$dataStoreVersion"
```